# Лучшая практика для кроссплатформенности в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, git

Лучшая практика для кроссплатформенности в Unity?

У меня есть проект, помогите мне с вопросом, я развертываю игру WebGL для 3 платформ веб-игр: VK play, Яндекс Игры, игры Facebook и, возможно, любые другие, у каждого есть собственный SDK, и они мешают друг другу, мне нужно решение, могу ли я разделить свой проект на любой другойслужба веб-игр?

Для разделения проекта на Android, IOS, ПК я используюAssembly Definition, но это не разделяет платформу на другие сервисы

1. Можно ли использовать ветки Git для любого другого веб-сервиса? Но если я хочу изменить базовый код, это создаст мне новую проблему с объединением всех ветвей WebGL. Пример: WebGL_Yandex_Games, WebGL_VK_Games, WebGL_Facebook_Games отображаются в репозитории
2. Создать для любого другого веб-сервиса, другого проекта Unity? Это не производительность, размер проекта больше 1 ГБ
3. Может быть с Assembly Definitionразделенным проектом на WebGL и содержит запись для всех веб-сервисов, но могу ли я узнать, какой веб-сервис используется сейчас? Вконтакте, Яндекс или Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Может сделать один интерфейс, а задать ему реализации под каждую платформу? Юнити вроде не добавляет в билд неиспользуемые скрипты

Comment: Я так и делаю, но как мне определить что сейчас пользователь использует VK а не Yandex?

Comment: Предполагаю что кидать запросы во все сервисы?

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Сделать разные билды под разные платформы

Answer (score 0):

Проект может весить и 1Гб и 2Гб и значения это не имеет. Может оказаться, что 90% веса проекта, это папка `Library` содержащая всякий кеш для редактора. Вес итогового билда НЕ СОВПАДАЕТ с весом проекта и всегда гораздо меньше!

Не думаю что фреймворки платформ сильно много весят что-бы создавать проекты с каждым отдельно. Функции у них одни и те-же и их нужно использовать под абстракцией, то-есть прокладкой описанной интерфейсами, для возможности одной строчкой менять api на другой.

Как узнать какой использовать в данный момент? `Facebook`, `VK`, `Yandex` или `Placeholder` заглушку для редактора? Ok Google: `unity 3d webgl get current url`... one minute later: [Application.absoluteURL](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-absoluteURL.html).